# Finish build trigger with feature branches

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Have a problem implementing following workflow.
I have a number of build configurations(for running unit tests) that i want to run all of them manually for a feature branch.

Feature branch is specified VCS root branch specification settings. All build configurations using the same VCS root.Git is used for version control.

To run those build configurations i've created dummy build configuration called 'Run unit tests' ,then i added a finish build trigger to those unit tests build configurations which i want to run . In trigger's build configuration i've selected 'Run unit tests' and on branch filter i've specified

```
+:*
```

to check all branches.

Then i run custom build for 'Run unit tests' build configuration and on changes tab selected some feature branch. But for some reason it triggers builds for those unit tests build configurations for  branch, not for the feature branch i've selected on changes tab.
Can you please advice wow to make it trigger subsequent builds on the same feature branch i've specified in custom build settings page ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the snapshot dependencies helped to resolve the issue.

If setup snapshot dependency in build configurations being triggered to 'Run unit tests' build configuration, then it operates on correct branch.